# SignalR server method is not calling from client side

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

I am using SignalR notification in my application and getting notification from server side. Also on client response to the notification I have called server side method I have defined in my hub. 
But it is not invoking from client side. I have created my hub in as different project then its client side. Below is my code snippet.

```
//Client side Implementation

$(function(){
    var hub = $connection.messageHub

    //client method which can be called from the server -                **Working**
    hub.client.broadcastMessage = function(message, clientId)
    {
      $(#messages).append("<p> + message +</p>")
    }          

    $connection.hub.start.done(function(){
        $("#btnOk").on('click', function(){
            //server method which is called from Ok button of popup -    **Not working**
            hub.server.signalRMessageBox("Ok", $connection.hub.id);
        });

    });
});



//Server side method:

public class MessageHub: Hub
{
    public void SignalRMessageBox(string message string clientId)
    {
      //Server side Implementation
    }
}
```

Please suggest what wrong I am doing in it.

Comment: you are supposed to have a `.` like this `$.connection.messageHub` and `$.connection.hub.start().done(function(){})` etc

Comment: so check your browser console for errors

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion teresko, however there is typing mistake in the above query. I have used only $.connection.messageHub in my actual implementation. The problem is with its implementation in my project but it is working in a demo application. I am creating hub class in a separate project to use it as a library in different projects in my solution.